# Entity Framework Core (7): load single entity by id

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, async-await, entity-framework-core

`.ToListAsync` is used to get a collection of items from DB in EF Core. That's clear. But what is the right way to get single item? In async way if possible.

```
public async static Task<Source> LoadEntityAsync(int sourceID)
{
    using (var db = new RPDBContext())
    {
        var sources =
            await
                db.Source
                    .Where(x => x.SourceID == sourceID)
                    .ToListAsync();
        // TODO that's like a hack:
        return sources.First();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Single and not First which is practically doing a blind try/catch/continue block. If there is more than one you should throw an error, which is what Single does.

Comment: FYI, did you see the @Liviu Sosu answer. According to the documentation, is sounds a really better answer than the one accepted.

Comment: @EricOuellet, I agree. Switched accepted answer, TY.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The approved answer is correct, but not the best from my point of view.

If you are searching by the id, use the Find(PropertyID) method like this:

db.Source.Find(SourceID)

where:

- db: database context
- Source: your entity type
- SourceId is the Primary key

It returns the object or null, if not found.
More details here: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/#:~:text=The%20Find%20method%20on%20DbSet,context%20or%20in%20the%20database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/#:%7E:text=The%20Find%20method%20on%20DbSet,context%20or%20in%20the%20database).

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification. Your answer seems really better in performance!!!

Answer (score 5):

You should use `SingleOrDefaultAsync` if you want the object to be unique.
If you know that the object is unique from domain restrictions or if you are accessing it through primary key then you can use `FirstOrDefaultAsync`.

```
var sources = await db.Source
            .Where(x => x.SourceID == sourceID)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

you can use another overload and shorten the query

```
var sources = await db.Source
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.SourceID == sourceID);
```

same rules apply to `FirstOrDefaultAsync`.

If you want to ensure that the object exists just remove the `OrDefault` part and use `SingleAsync` and `FirstAsync`.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding the Queryable.FooAsync() methods in EF Core. Do I need to reference some other package?

EDIT
Nevermind.  I had to add `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;` I figured it was something like that. Unfortunately EF Core doesn't seem to have API docs published anywhere.

Comment: @Homr Zodyssey, Good note on `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;` those Async are not part of Linq but EFCore instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to retrieve a single item, use `FirstOrDefaultAsync`:

```
public static Task<Source> LoadEntityAsync(int sourceID)
{
    using (var db = new RPDBContext())
    {
        return db.Source.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.SourceID == sourceID);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use First and not Single ? If there is more than one it SHOULD through an error, especially since you do not have any sorting logic. You should use SingleOrDefault

Comment: @Cesar If it should be an error then that should be enforced by your relational model, not by your query.

Comment: FirstOrDefault explicitity instructs the model to ignore any error, I've seen this buggy code written by so many developers who are afraid of errors for some reason, it's a try/catch/continue in disguise. And the logic is simply wrong. If you want to load an entity (which is by defintition unique) then why is your code asking for the first match ?!

Comment: @Cesar FirstOrDefault does **NOT** instruct the model to ignore errors. It instructs the context to only fetch one instance (SELECT TOP 1 ...). If the field you use to filter is the primary key then the database guarantees that there will never be more than one instance. So there is no need to check that. In the given example it is reasonable to assume that SourceID is indeed the primary key of the Source table.

Comment: @pescolino the logic is exactly the opposite. Since there should be no difference then the stricter more correct method should be used. A method that states explicitly that there should be one. An error will be thrown if someone somehow messes the primary key in the DB otherwise it will give the same exact performance. With your approach it's just another 
blind  catch/continue. Insisting on using First (why not Last?) is simply being stubborn. I've encountered many such developers who cry later about random behavior. FirstOrDefault DOES instruct the code to ignore the error.